# How to change to new Azure portal permanently

Tags: azure, azureportal

Every time I login to Azure portal, the classic one shows up and I have to click on "launch new portal". How do I make my default portal as the new one?

Thanks

-JS

Comment: If you use https://portal.azure.com (URL for new portal), that should take care of your problem.

Answer (score 3):

To use the new portal use portal.azure.com
To use the old one use manage.windowsazure.com